# LINQ-to-Entities Find DateTime difference

Tags: linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to compare difference of two DateTimes in an L2E query. I know that the translation of DateTime methods to Entity Framework is really problematic, and I need a precise comparison in minutes. I tried to compare the `Ticks` of `DateTime` but it wasn't supported. I can test for the same day, hour, and minute explicitly (using the methods in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime` class does this trick, and I don't know why regular DateTime still isn't supported yet), but it will be problematic for, say, midnight values, and I don't want to cope up with checking dates, then if they are different, check if the days are adjacent, and then the the hours/minutes, there must be a more convenient way. How do I compare the ticks (which is the most straightforward way to do this for me to check for, like 15 minutes of difference) in an L2E query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SqlFunctions object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx  I'm not sure if these are SQL Server specific or note...

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to find Datetime difference could be something like-

```
var p = (from ad in dcDistrict.ADULTs
                         where DateTime.Now.Subtract(ad.CREATED.Value).Minutes >= 15
                         select ad);
```